# 'httpd-vhost.conf' breaks WAMPServer?

Tags: apache-http-server, localhost, wamp, virtual-host, httpd

I am attempting to host a development website from my laptop using WAMPServer. My goal is to install WordPress and have users log in from their homes.

- I’ve successfully installed WAMPServer 2.2
- I’ve included `127.0.0.1 localhost` in my `hosts` file
- I’ve removed the `#` from the front of `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Now `localhost` works perfectly until I edit my `httpd-vhost.conf` file to include the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SeverAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/WampServer2/www"
    ErrorLog "C:/Program Files/WampServer2/www/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/Program Files/WampServer2/www/logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Once I restart WAMPServer, the icon stays orange. If I attempt to put WAMPServer online, I get an alert titled *Aestan Tray Menu* stating `Could not execute menu item (internal error). [Exception] Could not preform service action: the service has not been started`.

(Port 80 tested as "not actually used".)

When I run `httpd.exe`, a command-prompt opens then immediately closes before I can read it. I’ve tried various formats to `<VirtualHost *:80>` with no avail, however once I comment out my changes, I am able to successfully restart WAMPServer and access `localhost`.

I haven’t been able to find any posts about this problem anywhere.

**[EDIT]:** My error logs are not including any new entries when attempting to restart WAMPServer with `<VirtualHost *:80>` included, however when commented out, WAMPServer starts & stops without error and the following lines are added:

```
Child 10084: Child process is running
Child 10084: Acquired the start mutex.
Child 10084: Starting 64 worker threads.
Child 10084: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
Child 10084: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
Child 10084: Exit event signaled.
Child process is ending.
Child 10084: Released the start mutex
Child 10084: All worker threads have exited.
Child 10084: Child process is exiting Parent:
Child process exited successfully.
```

There is also a line before these that says `[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts`.

I’ve been trying to get this to work for days. Any ideas what’s wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar issues but manage to Print Screen my httpd.exe command-prompt before it closes. I figured out the error that was in following entry in my httpd-vhost.conf file.

**NameVirtualHost *:80**

nameVirtualHost is deprecated, it's neccessary to use just Listen 127.0.0.1:80

[My own corrected httpd-vhosts.conf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5tpxvvykajfc92k/httpd-vhosts.conf)

[My own WRONG httpd-vhosts.conf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mvys87pug39zjo1/httpd-vhosts_WRONG.conf)